# What happened in March 1991 when the IMB neutrino detector sprung a leak?

Tags: history, neutrinos, particle-detectors

When I was in grad school, I recall hearing a story something like this:

"Once upon a time, there was a neutrino detector (Cherenkov water detector--just a large bag [in my memory of the story it is more like a bag than a tank ??] of water surrounded by PMTs) located in a salt mine. One day it sprung a leak, and the water came pouring out and dissolved the salt cavity in which the detector was located. The detector was literally lost forever--as in, all the equipment was washed away [washed away to where? one might ask] and never seen again."

OK, most likely I am misremembering the story I heard; but I am wondering what grain of truth is behind it. (I heard the story sometime in the early 2010s, but it was a reference to something that had happened decades earlier: 80s sounds about right).

Here's what I've found so far: The [IMB experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irvine%E2%80%93Michigan%E2%80%93Brookhaven_(detector)) was a water Cherenkov detector located in a salt mine in Ohio. In [their paper describing the detector](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016890029390998W?via%3Dihub), they say: "At the end of March 1991, the data-taking with the IMB-3 phase was terminated, due to a water leak which could not be stemmed without emptying the detector." So there was a leak that was consequential enough to shut down the experiment permanently, but it doesn't sound completely catastrophic, as in the story I heard. But they only write a single sentence about the leak, and there could be an element of understatement there--maybe it was more catastrophic than described there. So I'm wondering if anyone knows more of the story of this leak.

A secondary question would be if there is another incident involving a different experiment that more closely matches the story as I remember it (the same IMB paper mentions that "several earlier experiments had been performed at this site with successful results").

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your actual physics related question is here, I only see a bunch of background and speculation.

Comment: @Triatticus Sorry about that! I've edited the question to make the question clearer.

Comment: I see, perhaps then it would be better for History of physics stackexchange then as I don't really see how this is a physics conceptual question as you are asking more about a historical recounting.